# How do closures work in runpy?

Tags: python, closures, runpy

I get unexpected behaviour when I try to run methods defined in a file loaded using the [runpy](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html) module. The methods do not see any variables (including imported modules) defined outside of that method. Here is how I am doing it:

```
#test.py
import runpy
env = runpy.run_path('test', {'y':'world'})
env['fn']()
```

~

```
#test
import re

print(re.compile(r'^hello', re.IGNORECASE).sub('', "hello world"))
x = "hello"
print(x)
print(y)

def fn():
    try:
        print(re.compile(r'^hello', re.IGNORECASE).sub('', "hello world"))
    except:
        print("No re")
    try:
        print(x)
    except:
        print("No x")
    try:
        print(y)
    except:
        print("No y")
```

My expected output of test.py would be:

```
 world
hello
world
 world
hello
world
```

because fn would form a closure for re, x and y.

However, instead I get:

```
 world
hello
world
No re
None
None
```

It looks like re isn't defined within fn even though it should be with normal closure behaviour. x and y are even stranger because they appear to be defined but set to None.

Why is this and how do closures work with runpy? How can I achieve normal behaviour such that fn can 'see' outside variables?

Answer (score 4):

OK, this is a curiosity of the way Python handles modules, which I know about but don't fully understand. I've come across it while working on IPython, where it's explained in [a comment](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L894).

When Python runs a module, it produces a module object, the attributes of which are the global names in the module. When the module falls out of scope and is being destroyed, these attributes are set to `None`. Code which was defined in the function then sees these as the globals, as you found. You can demonstrate this by adding `def g(): return globals()` to your file, then calling `env["g"]()`.

I don't know if there's a way round this with `runpy`. IPython uses some complicated code to reuse a module object for running other files, caching copies of its `__dict__` to keep the references therein alive. Have a look at the [`magic_run` function](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magic.py#L1445) if you're interested.